# CPU is 100% at multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu

First I've read all the posts here regarding this issue and I manged to progress a bit. However it seems I do need your help :)

I have a program with several threads, sometimes (not always) the CPU usage of the program is increasing up to 100% and never reduced until I shut down the program.

As I read in other similar posts, I ran the app using the visual studio (2012 - Ultimate).
I paused the app, and open the threads window.
There I pauses the threads until I've found the 4 threads which stuck the app.
The all refer to the same line of code (a call for constructor).
 I checked the constructor inside and outside and couldn't find any loop which could cause it.
To be more careful I've added break point to almost every line of code and resume the app. None of them have been triggered.

This is the line of code:

```
   public static void GenerateDefacementSensors(ICrawlerManager cm)
    {
        m_SensorsMap = new Dictionary<DefacementSensorType, DefacementSensor>();

        // Create instance of all sensors
        // For any new defacement sensor, don't forget to add an appropriate line here
        // m_SensorsMap.add(DefacementSensorType.[Type], new [Type]Sensor())
        try
        {

            if (m_SensorsMap.Count <= 0)
            {
                m_SensorsMap.Add(DefacementSensorType.BackgroundSensor, new BackgroundSensor());
                m_SensorsMap.Add(DefacementSensorType.TaglinesSensor, new TaglinesSensor(cm.Database));
                m_SensorsMap.Add(DefacementSensorType.SingleImageSensor, new SingleImageSensor());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem initializing defacement sensors");

        }


    }
```

The second "m_SensorsMap.Add" is marked with green arrow, as I understand it, it means it's still waiting to the first line to finish.

By the way, the m_SensorsMap.Count value is 3.

How can I find the problem?
Is it a loop?
Or maybe a deadlock (not make sense because it shouldn't be 100% cpu, right?)
It's pointless to upload a code because this is a huge project.
I need more general help like how to debug?
Is it could something else than a loop?

Because it's a bug that returns every while and than I'm not closing the app until I found the problem :)

Thanks in advance!!

Edit:
The constructors:

```
     public TaglinesSensor(IDatabase db)
    {
        m_DB = db;
    }
```

Comment: what type is `m_SensorsMap`? What happens inside the two constructors?

Comment: "Is it a loop?" Probably. Have you considered adding some logging in your application, so you can see what's happening? Adding some output at key points can give you valuable insight. Check out the `Trace` class. Or, if you already have logging support, add more detailed logging.

Comment: Rotem: m_SensorMap is dictionary with enum and class. Dictionary<DefacementSensorType, DefacementSensor>
inside the constructors it's just initializing db objects.

Comment: You'll need to show more code than you have for anyone to give you anything other than a wild guess.

Comment: Jim, you right regarding some output, but I'm assume it won't work because every place I thought about adding log I've put breakpoints and nothing happens.

Comment: @ShaulZuarets Then what do you expect from us?

Comment: @L.B What do u mean line 132? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Just a W.A.G - check what your cm.Database property does.

Comment: Have you tried to set the debugger to catch all exceptions as they are thrown? You are catching every exception, it seems, which is generally bad practice.

Comment: @MicroVirus How do I do it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Comment: If you line by line edit away the code in your constructor (until the constructor is empty) do you still get the CPU usage? can you pinpoint the issue that way? ATM this is just a guessing game - I doubt very much that anyone seeing this question can say what the issue is. You **have** to provide more info/debugging.

Comment: This is a big app with more than 200 classes. I don't think you can help by solving the problem. But maybe you can help me by give me new ideas how to find the problem? is there a way to see the problematic loop? is it could be something else than a loop?

Comment: This code has a Very Big code smell.  It is not protecting the collection with a lock.  Lots of things can go wrong when the collection gets corrupted internally by two threads modifying it concurrently, getting stuck in a loop is a distinct possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found the problem so I've changed the design on order not to call those constructors anymore.

Thanks for the guys who tried to help.

Shaul